# how to fill array of pointers with NULL?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have array of pointers:

```
private:
    LimitOrder* orders[Size];
```

In constructor i'm trying to fill it with NULL:

```
InternalIdAssigner::InternalIdAssigner(void):
    lastCleanId(0)
{
    std::fill(orders, orders + Size, NULL);
```

But this doesn't work, I receive error: `error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const int' to 'LimitOrder *'`

What is the right way to fill array field with NULL?

Comment: If you're using a C++03x or later compliant toolchain, just add `orders()` to your initializer list.

Comment: An std::for_each would suffice. Even better than that, use a smart pointer. They get set to nullptr in their constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is kind of clear, if you understand what `NULL` really is: a literal `0`.

When you pass `0` to a template, the deduced type is `int`, not a pointer type. While a literal `0` is implicitly convertible to any pointer type and will be a null pointer, after it if passed to `fill` it is just an `int` with value 0, which is not convertible to a pointer type.

In C++11 you could and should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. In C++03 you can also convert the pointer to the destination type:

```
std::fill(orders, orders + Size, static_cast<LimitOrder*>(0));
```

But then again, why go through the process in the first place when you can *zero-initialize* the array in the initializer list?

```
InternalIdAssigner::InternalIdAssigner()
   : lastCleanId(), orders() {}
```

Comment: the last doesn't work in Visual Studio 2012, but probably works in more modern compiler

Answer (score 4):

If you're using C++11:

```
std::fill(orders, orders + Size, nullptr);
```

otherwise:

```
std::fill(orders, orders + Size, static_cast<LimitOrder*>(NULL));
```

Or if you don't want to use a cast:

```
LimitOrder* tmp = NULL;
std::fill(orders, orders + Size, tmp);
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion:

Change

```
std::fill(orders, orders + Size, NULL);
```

to

```
std::fill(orders, orders + Size, (LimitOrder*)NULL);
```